# ?members command for my discord bot - discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So I've been trying to create a ?members command which lists all the users with a role.

So far I've got this:

```
if (message.content.startsWith("?members")) {
        let roleName = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");

        let membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member => {
            return member.roles.find("name", roleName);
        }).map(member => {
            return member.user.username;
        })

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
            "title": `Members in ${roleName}`,
            "description": membersWithRole.join("\n"),
            "color": 0xFFFF

        });

        return message.channel.send(embed);



    }
```

So, it works if you type the exact name of the role, but not when you ping it or type the first word. I've been trying for hours to figure out how to do it, and I figured I should ask for help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pings get translated into a code as they come through, there is a lot of information on how to parse them in the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work)  After it's parsed into a role id you can just use members.roles.get() because that is what they are indexed by.

As for finding a partial name, for that you are going to have to run a function on your find and use [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```
return member.roles.find(role => role.name.includes(roleName));
```

This will also work for find the whole name of course, so it can replace your existing line.

However, this may result in more than one role.  This is also true for searching by the entire role name, however, as there are no restrictions on duplicate named roles.  For this you may want to invert you design and search through message.guild.roles first for any matching roles, then search for members with the roles found.

Comment: When I replace the line with this code, the command doesn't show the members, even when i type the full name.

Comment: @Golden you used your variable and not the demo string I put?  I probably should have done that in my example, I'll edit.